# Does Task.WhenAny prioritize some tasks over others?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

When passing multiple completed tasks to Task.WhenAny does Task.WhenAny give a preference to which task completed Task will be returned?

Comment: why are you sending completed tasks to `Task.WhenAny`?

Comment: No. If you're adding completed tasks, the first completed task it comes across in the collection (iterating in a natural order, nothing crazy) will be returned. I highly doubt the order is specified anywhere, so behavior *could* change, not likely though. If no tasks are completed then it'll return the first task which *does* run to completion. [Relevant source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/TaskFactory.cs,db51a91904616672)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to know the exact behavior, you can often check the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/).  For instance, `WhenAny` can be found [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,762916332c77a130).

When looking through the source, note that the returned task is not one of your tasks, but an internally-created task (either a `CompleteOnInvokePromise` instance or continuation of it), whose `Result` will be one of your tasks.  In the case where you are passing completed tasks into `WhenAny`, the `Result` is immediately set to the first completed task it encounters.

Comment: Of course, there's also a race here, assuming the non-completed tasks are hot - if you have `{t1,t2,ct1,ct2}` where the `ct` items are already completed and the `t` ones weren't at the start of the call, one of `t1` and `t2` may complete *whilst* `WhenAny` is still looping through and setting things up. In short - if you pass a mixture of incomplete and complete tasks, you're certainly not guaranteed that one of the already completed tasks will be what you get handed back.