# Uncertainty about the behavior of Task.WhenAny

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

Say `task1`, `task2`, `task3` are tasks that I start at the beginning of the function, what does
`await Task.WhenAny(task1,task2,task3);` return if more than one task has finished before the code reaches that await statement? Is it a random task? The first from the arguments that finished? A list of the tasks that have completed?

It does not matter by the way, I'm just wondering if it's uncertain behavior or if there's a priority

Comment: Check [the method docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenany?view=net-8.0). It returns the task that completed, not an array. There's no restriction on *which* that will be if multiple tasks complete. If you care which one it was you'll have to check them for completion, or compare the result with one of the originals for equality

Comment: It returns a single task, so your third option ("list of tasks") can be excluded. Why does it matter for you which of the other two options is implemented?

Comment: Indeed, why does it matter? There are ways to address the actual question

Comment: A random Task that has `task.Completed == true`.

Comment: Even if the method would deterministically return the first completed task from the list, by the time you are evaluating it, a task earlier in the list could have completed in addition. So basically no difference to returning a random completed task.

Comment: Related: [Does Task.WhenAny prioritize some tasks over others?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39103527/does-task-whenany-prioritize-some-tasks-over-others)

Comment: The question is actually important, because the behavior of the `Task.WhenAny` could cause [left-side bias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70710153/how-to-merge-multiple-asynchronous-sequences-without-left-side-bias "How to merge multiple asynchronous sequences without left-side bias?") in some implementations.

Comment: The standard does not guarantee anything about the chosen task. It is an implementation detail. And you should not assume more. Especially since it is easy to check yourself.

Comment: @KlausGütter it doesn't matter, I was just wondering if it's uncertain or if there's a common pattern

Comment: There's no *defined* behavior which means whatever you see is the result of a specific implementation. You can [check the source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/9699f39112b2aea89a05a74199baf9049db85537/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs#L6407) but you'll see there are checks for optimizations for special cases, eg two or three tasks, and checks for already completed task. The leftmost is checked first but after that there's no guarantee what will happen.

Comment: In general, a continuation is added to input tasks to trigger a TaskCompletionSource. When a completion is triggered the code checks to see which task completed. While tasks are checked left to right both in special and [in the general case](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/TaskFactory.cs#L2290), nothing guarantees that some *other* task  won't complete before the check starts.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with this super simple application:

```
TaskCompletionSource<object> tsc = new();
CancellationTokenSource cts = new(1_000);
cts.Token.Register(() => tsc.SetResult((object)null), useSynchronizationContext: false);
var task1 = tsc.Task;
var task2 = Task.Delay(1_000);
var task3 = Task.Run(async () => { await Task.Delay(1_000); });

var res = await Task.WhenAny(task1, task2, task3);

Console.WriteLine($"Task1: {task1.Id}");
Console.WriteLine($"Task2: {task2.Id}");
Console.WriteLine($"Task3: {task3.Id}");
Console.WriteLine($"res: {res.Id}");
```

Here we have three tasks and all will complete in a second. If you run this application multiple times then `res.Id` will be one of the three tasks depending the task scheduling.

---

Now, let's extend it with tasks that are completed before reaching the `Task.WhenAny`

```
TaskCompletionSource<object> tsc = new();
CancellationTokenSource cts = new(1_000);
cts.Token.Register(() => tsc.SetResult((object)null), useSynchronizationContext: false);
var task1 = tsc.Task;
var task2 = Task.Delay(1_000);
var task3 = Task.Run(async () => { await Task.Delay(1_000); });
var task4 = Task.Run(() => {});
var task5 = Task.Run(() => {});

var res = await Task.WhenAny(task1, task2, task3, task5, task4);

Console.WriteLine($"Task1: {task1.Id}");
Console.WriteLine($"Task2: {task2.Id}");
Console.WriteLine($"Task3: {task3.Id}");
Console.WriteLine($"Task4: {task4.Id}");
Console.WriteLine($"Task5: {task5.Id}");
Console.WriteLine($"res: {res.Id}");
```

> what does await Task.WhenAny(task1,task2,task3); if more than one task has finished before the code reaches that await statement?

In my experiments `res.Id` was always `task4.Id`.

> Is it a random task?

The above example is a bit bias. So, lets change the `task4` and `task5` to `Task.Delay(10);`.
In this case `res.Id` will be `task4.Id` or `task5.Id` depending on scheduling.

> The first from the arguments that finished?

No, it does not matter whether you add `task4` before or after `task5` to the parameter list of `Task.WhenAny`.

> A list of the tasks that have completed?

No. If you need that a simple Linq query can return that

```
List<Task> tasks = [task1, task2, task3, task5, task4];
var res = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);

var completedTaskIds = tasks.Where(t => t.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion).Select(t => t.Id).ToArray();
```